# EA Origin offline mode time tracking

Tags: origin

So I'm on pc and I was wondering if Origin tracks your time played if you start a game in offline mode?

Comment: How do you start the game?

Comment: I put Origin in offline mode and then I just click play on the game

Comment: So you're using the "Origin" program to start the game? In that case I would say that it would definitely still be able to track your time and upload it later, but I don't know if it actually does. Someone else has to answer that.